# Not able to Switch Layout to RTL when arabic text is sent over Push Notification in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub, android-push-notification, android-remoteview

So i'm trying to send Arabic Text over push notification, i have an image and a textview in a remoteview, when i send the text in english it works perfectly, but if i send it as arabic, then i'm able to receive the text but i'm not able to show it in RTL form, i've enabled RTL in manifest and also used

```
android:autoMirrored="true"
```

but for some reason, the text aligns itself onto the right but the image remains on the left itself, which shouldnt be the case

this is my layout, any help would be deeply appreciated

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp">

   <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/big_icon"
     android:layout_width="40dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:paddingBottom="1dp"
     android:autoMirrored="true"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:paddingLeft="2dp"
     android:paddingRight="2dp"
     android:src="@mipmap/icon"/>

   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/content_title"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:maxLines="2"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/big_icon"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:text="Notification Sample App"
     android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what i'm getting

[image: In English]

[image: In Arabic]

Comment: Add the line `android:supportsRtl="true"` in  AndroidManifest.xml .

Comment: I've already enabled it, since my app supports localization, it's already there

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589596/android-set-rtl-support-on-push-notification.

Answer (score 0):

use this inside textview android:textAlignment="start"

Comment: It's more about the image I feel, as you can see in the screenshot